# Не понимаю, как работает await и Task

Tags: c#, многопоточность, async-await

Это код, вызывающий диалоговое окно в Avalonia:

```
public async Task<TResult> ShowDialogAsync<TResult>() 
{
    return await GetWindow().ShowDialog<TResult>(m_target); 
}
```

И он работает успешно. Я попытался избавиться от async-await:

```
public TResult ShowDialog<TResult>() 
{
   var result = GetWindow().ShowDialog<TResult>(m_target);
   return result.Result;
}
```

Но диалоговое окно не отрисовывается, и закрыть его становится невозможно. Видимо, происходит взаимная блокировка. И как это обойти?

Comment: [Статьи по теме на хабре](https://habr.com/ru/search/?q=async%20await&target_type=posts&order=relevance)...

Comment: А зачем вообще это нужно? Смысл в чём? Ваш вопрос задан с [ошибкой XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/373567).

Comment: Смысл был в том, чтобы избавиться от асинхронности, но, как говорят, что не стоит этого делать

Comment: @aepot Зачем вы свой ответ удалили? Он тоже полезный, в случае такой простой функции я бы наверное выбрал ваш вариант. Сам я про него просто забыл, когда свой ответ писал.

Comment: @CrazyElf допишите решение к себе в ответ тогда, я не против, вдруг и правда кому-то полезно будет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А зачем вы хотите ухудшить код?

```cs
public async Task<TResult> ShowDialogAsync<TResult>() 
{
    return await GetWindow().ShowDialog<TResult>(m_target); 
}
```

В этом коде в момент вызова `await` поток освобождается и `UI` может обрабатывать события - отрисовывать окна, обрабатывать ввод пользователя, рисовать что-то, всё замечательно. Как только диалоговое окно закроется, будет получен и возвращён результат работы.

```cs
public TResult ShowDialog<TResult>() 
{
   var result = GetWindow().ShowDialog<TResult>(m_target);
   return result.Result;
}
```

Здесь поток блокируется в момент ожидания результата работы задачи `result.Result`, управление никуда не передаётся. Причём, видимо, это был поток `UI`, который в любой системе ровно один. Таким образом `UI` "висит", не может обрабатывать диалог, который вы хотели показать, программа "намертво повисла".

Асинхронность при работе с `UI` - это прекрасно, пользуйтесь ей, не нужно от неё избавляться.

**Дополнение** - вариант от aepot.

Если `await` - последний и единственный в методе, а также не находится в блоке `try-catch` или `using`, можно просто убрать и `async` и `await` не затронув поведение метода. Вы просто пробрасываете выше `Task`, который возвращает вызываемый в коде метод.

```cs
public Task<TResult> ShowDialogAsync<TResult>() 
{
    return GetWindow().ShowDialog<TResult>(m_target); 
}
```

Или, если использовать современную версию `C#` для однострочного кода:

```cs
public Task<TResult> ShowDialogAsync<TResult>() => GetWindow().ShowDialog<TResult>(m_target);
```

Answer (score 1):

Оставлю тут:

Если присмотреться к [исходнику](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/master/src/Avalonia.Controls/Window.cs#L755): то при вызове `ShowDialog` формируется `TaskCompletionSource`, которая подписывается на событие закрытия формы и ждет его выполнения. А само открытие и формирование формы происходит в потоке `UI`.

Если вызвать `Task.Result` то произойдет блокировка вызывающего потока `UI` и форма не успеет отобразится, а событие закрытия окажется в подвешенном состоянии.

Как говорилось выше, без асинхронности здесь никак. Сама логика вызова диалогового окна подразумевает блокировку основного окна, вывода диалога, получения `TResult`/`DialogResult` при закрытии диалога и возврат управления на основное окно.